# Incorrect syntax near GOTO label in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am using a GOTO statement inside a try block and also in catch block in a stored procedure.When it comes to the definition of GOTO label after END catch, it shows incorrect syntax error. below is the procedure. Error comes at 'AuditLog :' in the procedure. please help me with this.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_PIP_Employee]
    @Flag int = 1,
    @Empid int = 0,
    @Name nvarchar(500) = '',
    @Designation nvarchar(200) = '',
    @Department nvarchar(200) = '',
    @DateofJoin datetime = '' ,
    @Phone nvarchar(3000) = '',
    @Isactive int = 1,
    @LoginUser nvarchar(500) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON ;
    DECLARE @r int;

    BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        DECLARE @errorMessage VarChar(8000), 
                @errorSeverity Int,
                @errorState Int,
                @ReturnId Int,
                @AlCode varchar(50),
                @AlDesc varchar(1000),
                @AlOp varchar(50),
                @AlStatus varchar(50)

        IF (@Flag = 1)
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.PIP_Employee 
                       GROUP BY Name, Phone 
                       HAVING COUNT(ID) > 0 
                          AND Name = @Name AND Phone = @Phone)
            BEGIN
                SET @ReturnId = 0
                SET @AlCode = 'ERROR_1001'
                SET @AlDesc = CONCAT('Add Record of ',@Name,' failed due to duplicate entry')
                SET @AlOp = 'ADD'
                SET @AlStatus = 'ERROR'
                GOTO AuditLog
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.PIP_Employee (Name, Designation, Department, DateofJoin, Phone, IsPresent) 
                VALUES (@Name, @Designation, @Department, @DateofJoin, @Phone, @Isactive)

                SET @ReturnId = 1
            END
        END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SET @AlCode = ERROR_SEVERITY()
        SET @AlDesc = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        SET @AlOp = 'SQL TRANSACTION FAILURE'
        SET @AlStatus = ERROR_STATE();
        GOTO AuditLog  

        IF (@@trancount > 0)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END CATCH

AuditLog :
    INSERT INTO dbo.PIP_AuditLog (Aud_Code, Aud_Desc, Aud_Operation, Aud_Status, Aud_Createddate, Aud_ActionBy) 
    VALUES (@AlCode, @AlDesc, @AlOp, @AlStatus, GETDATE(), @LoginUser)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
```

`AuditLog :` seems to be an incorrect syntax.

Comment: Why are you using GOTO here?  Just use TRY/CATCH.  And you have to rollback before writing to the audit log, or else your audit log will get rolled back.

Comment: So if `@flag` is anything but 1, your procedure does NOTHING except auditing?

Comment: i want to write update , delete and select using different flag in the same procedure. and i want to log error details as well. So if exception occured then also want to add exception details in auditlog table. thats why i write code in catch block.. is there any another method to render this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using an IDE with syntax checking like SQL Server Management Studio, you might want to check out some free tools like https://ubitsoft.com/t-sql-beautilyzer/.

This indicates that line 68 is bad.  Namely that labels should NOT have a space between the label and the ':'